# Implementing interfaces in C++

Tags: c#, c++, interface, multiple-inheritance, porting

I usually program in C# but am trying to do a bit of C++ and am struggling somewhat trying to implement interfaces in C++.

In C# I'd do something like this:

```cs
class Base<T>
{
    public void DoSomething(T value)
    {
        // Do something here
    }
}

interface IDoubleDoSomething
{
    void DoSomething(double value);
}

class Foo : Base<double>, IDoubleDoSomething
{
}
```

In C++ I've implemented it like this:

```cpp
template <class T>
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void DoSomething(T value)
    {
        // Do something here
    }
};

class IDoubleDoSomething
{
public:
    virtual void DoSomething(double value) = 0;
};

class Foo : public Base<double>, public IDoubleDoSomething
{
};
```

The problem is that I **cannot instantiate Foo because it is abstract** (doesn't implement DoSomething). I realise I can implement DoSomething and just call the method on Base but I was hoping there is a better way of doing this. I have other classes which inherit from base with different data types and I have other classes which inherit from IDoubleDoSomething which don't use Base.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is so bad with this, and in what way could it be "better"?

Comment: I suppose "better" would be acting like the C# version where 'Foo' inherits the method from Base and doesn't need any implementation. I guess there is nothing really bad with making an implementation of each method from Base in Foo, it just feels messy.

Comment: It is messy, but I've never found a better way :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted, the two functions in the base classes are unrelated (despite having the same name and argument types), as they have no common base class.  If you want them to be related, you need to give them a common base class.

Also, in general, if you want multiple inheritance to work properly, you need to declare your non-private base classes as `virtual`.  Otherwise, if you ever have common base classes (as you often need for this style of code), bad things will happen.

So given that, you can make your example work as follows:

```
template <class T>
class IDoSomething {
public:
    virtual void DoSomething(T value) = 0;
};

template <class T>
class Base : public virtual IDoSomething<T>
{
public:
    virtual void DoSomething(T value)
    {
        // Do something here
    }
};

class IDoubleDoSomething : public virtual IDoSomething<double>
{
};

class Foo : public virtual Base<double>, public virtual IDoubleDoSomething
{
};
```

Comment: This seems to be the closest to what I was trying to achieve and, since I own the 'Base', it works well for my scenario. If I wasn't the owner of 'Base' then I guess the other solutions here would be more applicable.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following c++ code

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void DoSomething1(){}
};

template<typename t>
void MethodExpectsDosomething1( t f )
{
    f.DoSomething1();
}

template<typename t>
void MethodExpectsDosomething2( t f )
{
    f.DoSomething2();
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    MethodExpectsDosomething1<Foo>( f );

    MethodExpectsDosomething2<Foo>( f );

    return 0;
}
```

In C++ you can use `Foo` without it implementing a `IDoSomething1` and `IDoSomething2`. The second method `MethodExpectsDosomething2` will simply fail to compile as `Foo` doesn't have the `DoSomething2` method.

In C# such construct is not possible and forces you to have `IDoSomething1` and `IDoSomething2` interface and specify that as a [type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx).

**So maybe you need to look at your code and see if such interfaces are needed at all ?**

Comment: the problem with duck-typing is that it isn't self-documenting, while the solution involving polymorphism IS self-documenting.

Comment: If duck-typing was so bad... C# 4.0 would not have introduced it as `dynamic` keyword. Just because you are given an axe doesn't mean you have to chop your legs

Comment: may I remind you that the argument "it's popular, so it cannot be any bad" is not a good one? If you are the user of a templatized function, how do you figure out which kind of functionalities that function requests from your object, and with which semantics? This problem doesn't exists with dynamic polymorphism, since the interface IS the documentation.

Comment: @akappa: Interface itself is a poor documentation. Sure, you see what member signatures, but that's rarely enough to create a concrete implementation that will work with existing code. I don't think I've seen a case that didn't include assumptions that cannot be made part of the signature. And concepts are a way of documenting template argument requirements (also `template <typename Concept>` convention).

Comment: @akappa: (Point being, you need to read external documentation or the code, anyway).

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: I agree with you that the information contained in a member function signature hardly is sufficient to fully understand its supposed behavior, but usually interfaces are commented with the intended behavior, so the documentation is not "external" and, even if it is, it's a lot easier to search for it on the interwebz, since you have a precise name to put in the search field. On the other hand, searching for concept's documentation is usually harder, since the documentation is almost exclusively external and not always the convention you mention is followed.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, pure virtual functions must always be overridden in a derived class; they can't inherit overrides from other base classes like that. If you need dynamic polymorphism, I don't think there's any sensible alternative to writing a function in `Foo` that calls the `Base` function. Note that the `Base` function doesn't need to be virtual.

Depending on how you're using these classes (in particular whether the real type of each instance of the interface is known at compile time), you may be able to use static polymorphism to inject your particular implementation class into its user as a template parameter; for example:

```
// No explicit interface specification with static polymorphism
class Foo : public Base<double>
{
    // Inherits DoSomething(double)
};

// Template can used with any class that impelements a 
// "DoSomething" function that can accept a double.
template <class DoubleDoSomething>
void DoSomethingWithDouble(DoubleDoSomething & interface, double value)
{
    interface.DoSomething(value);
}

// This particular specialisation uses a "Foo" object.
Foo foo;
DoSomethingWithDouble(foo, 42);
```

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, `Base::DoSomething` and `IWhatever::DoSomething` are two unrelated functions (even if there weren't any pure virtual functions in this, you wouldn't be able to call `DoSomething` on a `Foo` object, anyway). `Base` needs to inherit from `IWhatever` for this to work.

That said, ask yourself if you actually need this. Generic programming with templates (and concepts, which are sort of like interfaces — see [Boost.ConceptCheck](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm)) is usually a better solution in C++ than runtime subtype polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

You could pass a second template parameter to Base, the interface that it is to implement:

```
template <typename T, class Interface>
class Base : public Interface { ... };

class Foo : public Base<double, IDoubleDoSomething> { ... };
```

For extra bonus points you could templatise IDoubleDoSomething (so it's eg `IDoSomething<double>`), or use a traits class to map the type T to the relevant interface.

Answer (score -1):

Provided everything else is in order, this should work.

```
class Foo : public Base<double>
{
};
```

In your original code Foo would have 2 void DoSomething(double value) methods (1 being abstract).
That would be an Base part and an IDoubleDoSomething part.
Foo::Base and Foo::IDoubleDoSomething.
You could try it by temporarily giving and implementation to IDoubleDoSomething.DoSomething().

But since Foo already "is a" Base" you have what you need without IDoubleDoSomething.

Comment: The reason for using an interface is to pass a pointer to it without requiring the definition of the base or derived class. Eliminating the interface class is going backwards.